# Resume media player (Spotify, Apple Music, etc) while my ios app is in background

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio

Going to ask this question because I cannot find a sufficient answer. I have an application that needs to play some audio. It needs to pause the current media player (Spotify, Apple Music, etc), and when my audio is done playing it needs to release and notify such that the previously playing media resumes. This works properly when the screen is on, and my app is active on the screen, aka my application is running in the foreground. However, this does not work properly when my application is in the background (eg the screen is locked, or another app is present on the screen).

Here is the setup that works when my app is on screen in the foreground.

Initial setup

```
-(void) viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    
    // deactivate session
    BOOL success = [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:NO error: nil];
    if (!success) { NSLog(@"deactivationError"); }
    // set audio session category AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord
    success = [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord withOptions:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionMixWithOthers error:nil];
    if (!success) { NSLog(@"setCategoryError"); }
    // set audio session mode to default
    success = [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setMode:AVAudioSessionModeDefault error:nil];
    if (!success) { NSLog(@"setModeError"); }
    // activate audio session
    success = [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES error: nil];
    if (!success) { NSLog(@"activationError"); }
```

The code below is called when I want to pause the background audio player (Spotify, Apple Music, etc.):

```
-(void) pauseBackgroundAudio {
    
    // activate a non-mixable session
    // set audio session category AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord
    BOOL success;
    AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionsNone = 0;
    success = [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord withOptions:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionsNone error:nil];
    if (!success) { NSLog(@"setCategoryError"); }

    // set audio session mode default
    success = [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setMode:AVAudioSessionModeDefault error:nil];
    if (!success) { NSLog(@"setModeError"); }

    // activate audio session
    success = [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES error: nil];
    if (!success) { NSLog(@"activationError"); }
    
    NSLog(@"starting playback (pauseBackgroundAudio)");
    
    NSURL* sound = [[NSBundle mainBundle ] URLForResource:@"path1" withExtension:@"wav"];
    NSLog(@"%@", sound);
    AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:sound error:NULL];
    [audioPlayer play];
}
}
```

The following code is called when I want to resume the background audio (Spotify, Apple Music, etc.):

```
-(void) resumeBackgroundAudio {
    NSError *sessionError = nil;
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:NO
                    withOptions:AVAudioSessionSetActiveOptionNotifyOthersOnDeactivation
                          error:&sessionError];

    NSLog(@"stopping playback (resumeBackgroundAudio)");
}
```

This works fine WHEN MY APP IS ON SCREEN. However when my app is backgrounded, or the screen is off, pausing the previously playing audio does not work properly (unpausing and resuming works correctly).

When the app is in the foreground everything works perfect. When the app is in the background or the screen is off I see the following error:

```
ATAudioSessionClientImpl.mm:274   activation failed. status = 560557684
```

I see the above error code is this:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfaudio/avaudiosession/errorcode/cannotinterruptothers

If you have any ideas on how to make this code work properly when my app is in the background that would be awesome!